# What is a default split_size in model training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When splitting the data into the test and training data what split size should I choose?

I was told that set by default is 80 % for training data,and 20 % for test data, can somebody ensure me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default split size in   [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) is 75% training and 25% testing data split. Data splits should depend on the task at hand.

The rule of thumb is that you have enough representative data that represent your problem to train a model and a enough representative data to validate your trained model.